# Determines the numbers removed

Tags: arithmetic

Four consecutive even numbers are removed from the set $\left\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\right\}$. If the arithmetic mean of the remaining numbers is 51.5625, determine the value of n and which numbers are removed:

Attemp: $ 515625= (1+1+(n-1) \cdot r) \cdot \frac{n}{2}$. But it doesn't work

Answer: N = 100, and the numbers taken are 22, 24, 25 and 28

Comment: I think your last sentence has a typo: $25$ is not an even number.

Comment: I would start by expressing the arithmetic mean as a fraction in lowest terms, rather than as a decimal.  Then the denominator will be a divisor of $n-4$.

Comment: As $51.5625=\frac{825}{16}$, I believe that $n-4\equiv 0\pmod{16}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the four evens are
$$
r-3, r-1, r+1, r+3
$$
where $r$ is some odd number. Then the sum of the set-with-items-removed is
$$
Q = \left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right) - 4r
$$
and the number of items is $n-4$, so the average is
$$
\frac{\left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right) - 4r}{n-4} = 51 \frac{9}{16}
$$
Cross-multiply to get
$$
16 \left(\left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right) - 4r\right) = 459(n-4)
$$
so
\begin{align}
 8n(n+1) - 64r &= 459(n-4)\\
 8n^2 + 8n - 64r  &= 459n-1836 \\
 8n^2 - 451n - 64r + 1836  &= 0 \\
\end{align}
Rewriting $r = 2k+1$ (because it's odd), we get
\begin{align}
0 &=  8n^2 - 451n - 64r + 1836 \\
0 &=  8n^2 - 451n - 64(2k+1) + 1836 \\
0 &=  8n^2 - 451n - 128k - 64 + 1836 \\
0 &=  8n^2 - 451 n - 128k + 1772 \\
451n - 1772 &=  8n^2  - 128k  \\
451n - 1772 &=  8(n^2  - 16k)  \\
\end{align}
so $8$ must divide $451n - 1772$. Taken mod 8, this says that
$0 = 3n - 4 (\bmod 8)$.

Then I'd observe that for $n > 120$, the average of the numbers is at least $58.5$, and that for $n < 90$, the average is at most $7$, so you've only got a few values of $n$ to try, namely $n = 92, 100, 108, 116$ (because of the mod-8 restriction).

Plug in each of these $n$ values and see whether there's a nonnegative integer $k$ that gets you the result you want.

Comment: Note that you already had a $n\equiv 4 \bmod 16$ restriction from the observation that $51.5625=\frac{825}{16}=51 \frac{9}{16}$

Comment: Indeed...but I was just writing down what I thought as I thought of it, and I didn't notice that. :(